# PHP Version compatibility issue with EE module

Tags: ee3, module, php-errors, update, php7

I have created a plugin that is running good in PHP v5.5.x. When I upgrade my PHP version to 7.x it gives me errors.

Code that is suspicious is:

```
$this->EE =& get_instance();
```

Error is:

> only variables should be passed by reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As error says, **PHP 7** is only allow variables to passed by reference not an instance. You now need to remove that line and replace all `$this->EE` calls to `ee()`. That will work for you.

Comment: This works, I know it will work if I replace instance reference call by `ee()`. However I was looking for workaround with `$this->EE`.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure you don't need this in a plugin `$this->EE =& get_instance();
ref https://docs.expressionengine.com/v2/development/plugins.html

Comment: I know it is not needed, but i want to use `$this->EE` instead of `ee()` call